# How to type cast variables inside a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm looping through an array using a `foreach` loop:

```
$attributes = array( 'drink', 'price', 'amount' );

foreach ( $attributes as $key ) {
    $info[$key] = $key;
}
```

How can I type cast my `$key` variable differently each time the loop runs? For example, I need drink to be type `string`, price to be `float` and amount to be `int`.

Please note, this is a simplified example of my code. Type casting the keys before the loop is run isn't suitable in my case.

I tried the following but it didn't seem to work:

```
$attributes = array( 'drink' => 'string', 'price' => 'float', 'amount' => 'int' );

foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value ) {
    $info[$key] = ($value) $key;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: The key being what you cast it as? `$attributes = array("string" => array("drink"), "float" => array("price"), "int" => array("amount"));`

Comment: I tried making the array an associative array with the types as values. But that didn't seem to work

Comment: just write an if elseif else inside the loop block, or switch, whatever suits you best

Comment: You want to cast the string `'price'` to a `float`? Or you want to ensure the value of the key `price` is a `float`? Where does that value come from then?

Comment: @deceze sorry for the very basic example, I know it doesn't quite make sense. I had a hard time trying to explain this one. Please see the accepted answer for what I was trying to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I use the key to then call either [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval), [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval) or [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval))

```
$attributes = array("str" => 'drink',"float"=> "10.5","int"=> "10" );
foreach ( $attributes as $k => $key ) {
    $k.="val";
    $info[$key] = $k($key);
}

var_dump($info);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["drink"]=>
  string(5) "drink"
  ["10.5"]=>
  float(10.5)
  [10]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an assoc array and use the key as the type cast. For example

```
$attributes = array("string" => array("drink"), 
                    "float" => array("price"), 
                    "int" => array("amount"));

$array = array();
foreach($attributes as $cast => $val) {
   switch($cast) {
      case 'int' :
        $array[] = (int) $val;
        break;
      case 'float' :
        $array[] = (float) $val;
        break;
      case 'string' :
      default :
        $array[] = (string) $val;
        break;
   }
}
```

https://eval.in/312808

#### Edit

If there are multiple elements needed to type cast, store them in an array (like above), and call [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map). For example:

```
$attributes = array("string" => array("drink"), 
                    "float" => array("price"), 
                    "int" => array("amount"));

$array = array();
foreach($attributes as $cast => $val) {
   switch($cast) {
      case 'int' :
        $array[] = array_map("intval",$val);
        break;
      case 'float' :
        $array[] = array_map("floatval",$val);
        break;
      case 'string' :
      default :
        $array[] = array_map("strval",$val);
        break;
   }
}
```

https://eval.in/312812

Comment: just wondering why you've made each value an array? `array("drink")` etc?

Comment: To have the ability for more elements. You can't have 2 keys named `string`. In the OP *"Please note, this is a simplified example of my code"* I assumed that meant there is more to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `settype()` function, here adapted to your example:

```
$attributes = array( 'drink' => 'string', 'price' => 'float', 'amount' => 'int' );

foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value ) {
    settype($key, $value);
    $info[$key] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order in `$attributes` is constant you can try:

```
$attributes = array( 'drink', 'price', 'amount' );

foreach ( $attributes as list($drink, $price, $amount) ) {
    $info['drink'] = $drink;
    $info['price'] = (float) $price;
    $info['amount'] = (int) $amount;
}
```